# iOS Eureka Change section header after creation

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am reloading data in a Eureka form in viewDidAppear method:

i have something like:

**in viewDidLoad()**

```
form +++ Section("contacts-selected")
```

**in viewDidAppear()**

```
if let section = form.sectionBy(tag: "contacts-selected") {
    section.removeAll()
    guard let contacts = dataprovider.getContacts() else{
        return
    }
    \\ does not work
    section.header?.title = "Contacts: \(contacts.count) selected" 

    for item in contacts {
        let row = Label() {
            $0.title = item.description 
        }
        section.append(row)
    }
}
```

the problem is that I need to change the section title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had been working on your question an here are my results, first of all you need to be sure that your section have the tag that you need later, so you need to use this code instead of your `viewDidLoad()`code

```
form +++ Section("contacts-selected"){section in
            section.tag = "contacts-selected"
    }
```

and later you can get your section and change the title, but if you don´t call 
`section.reload()` in the interface will never be updated, so add `section.reload()` below of your `section.header?.title = "Contacts: \(contacts.count) selected"`

```
    if let section = form.sectionBy(tag: "contacts-selected") {
    section.removeAll()
    guard let contacts = dataprovider.getContacts() else{
        return
    }
    \\ does not work
    section.header?.title = "Contacts: \(contacts.count) selected" 
    section.reload() //this is the important part to update UI

    for item in contacts {
        let row = Label() {
            $0.title = item.description 
        }
        section.append(row)
    }
   }
```

Here is a little example code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  EurekaExamplesSwift3
//
//  Created by Reinier Melian on 11/5/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Reinier Melian. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Eureka

class ViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        form = Section("Section1")
            <<< TextRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Text Row"
                row.placeholder = "Enter text here"
            }.onCellSelection({ (textCell, textRow) in
                if let section = self.form.sectionBy(tag: "contacts-selected") {

                    section.header?.title = "Header Changed"
                    section.reload()

                }
            })
            <<< PhoneRow(){
                $0.title = "Phone Row"
                $0.placeholder = "And numbers here"
            }
            +++ Section("Section2")
            <<< DateRow(){
                $0.title = "Date Row"
                $0.value = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 0) as Date
        }

        form +++ Section("Contacts"){section in
                section.tag = "contacts-selected"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I hope this helps you, best regards

Comment: just a quick note, doing `+++Section(){$0.tag = "tag"}` and then changing the header later would not work. `section.header` will be nil in this case. you need to add an initial header title `+++Section("title"){$0.tag= "tag"}`